# Visualizing weights of trained neural network in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Hi I trained an auto encoder network with convolution layer of 96*96*32

Now I get the weights of my model named autoencoder by

```
layer=autoencoder.layers[1]
W=layer.get_weights()
```

As w is a list, please help me sort it's elements and visualize the trained kernels.
I am guessing it should be 32 kernels with 96×96 size

When I type

```
len(w)
```

It gives 2 so I have 2 arrays

The top array has 9 subarrays each with 32 numbers
The last array has 32 elements. So it must be bias

```
[array([[[[-6.56146603e-03, -1.51752336e-02, -3.76937017e-02,
           -4.55160812e-03,  1.26366820e-02, -2.97747254e-02,
            3.76312323e-02, -1.56892575e-02,  2.03932393e-02,
            3.29606095e-03,  3.76580656e-02,  6.99581252e-03,
           -4.97130565e-02,  3.63005586e-02,  3.70187908e-02,
            2.63699284e-03,  4.42482866e-02,  8.26128479e-03,
            3.44854854e-02,  1.94760375e-02,  3.91177870e-02,
           -6.67006942e-03,  5.64308763e-02, -1.55166145e-02,
           -3.46037326e-03, -3.14556211e-02, -2.31548538e-03,
            5.77888393e-04,  2.17472352e-02, -8.16953406e-02,
            1.54041937e-02, -3.55066173e-02]],

         [[ 7.61649990e-03, -6.52475432e-02,  2.02584285e-02,
           -4.36152853e-02, -7.94242844e-02, -6.29556971e-03,
           -2.17294712e-02,  3.30206454e-02,  3.47386077e-02,
           -2.77627818e-03,  4.49984707e-02, -3.03241126e-02,
           -3.36903334e-02,  2.34354921e-02,  3.31020765e-02,
           -7.81059638e-03, -9.54489596e-03, -1.07985372e-02,
            4.10569459e-02,  5.06392084e-02, -1.64809041e-02,
            8.42852518e-03, -6.24148361e-03,  1.38165271e-02,
            4.47277874e-02, -1.68551356e-02,  2.87279133e-02,
           -4.17906158e-02, -3.29194516e-02,  5.37550561e-02,
           -3.10864598e-02, -4.53849025e-02]],

         [[ 5.37880100e-02,  2.00091377e-02, -8.04780126e-02,
            2.05146279e-02, -6.41385652e-03,  2.94176023e-02,
            2.42049675e-02,  2.98423916e-02,  1.30865928e-02,
           -9.23016574e-03, -2.63463743e-02, -1.58412699e-02,
           -4.76215854e-02, -1.53328422e-02, -2.54222248e-02,
            1.03113698e-02,  1.97005924e-02, -1.09527409e-02,
           -4.29149866e-02,  1.15255425e-02,  3.65356952e-02,
            2.26275604e-02,  8.76231957e-03, -1.82650369e-02,
            4.30952013e-02, -1.58966344e-03,  1.01399068e-02,
            7.15927547e-03,  2.70794444e-02, -1.93151142e-02,
            2.06329934e-02, -3.24055366e-02]]],


        [[[ 7.32885906e-04, -5.99233769e-02,  1.01583647e-02,
            2.62707975e-02, -1.60765275e-02,  4.54364009e-02,
            1.22182900e-02,  1.77695882e-02,  3.40870097e-02,
           -3.20678158e-03,  1.94115974e-02, -5.89495376e-02,
            5.51430099e-02,  1.08586736e-02, -2.14386974e-02,
           -1.10124948e-03, -1.41514605e-02, -8.40184465e-03,
           -4.09237854e-02,  2.27938611e-02,  2.82027805e-03,
            3.99805643e-02, -5.23957238e-02, -6.65743649e-02,
           -1.86213956e-03,  1.84283289e-03,  8.22036352e-04,
           -2.04587094e-02, -4.95675243e-02,  5.40869832e-02,
            4.00022417e-02, -4.74570543e-02]],

         [[-3.73015292e-02,  9.84914601e-03,  9.94246900e-02,
            3.19805741e-02,  8.14174674e-03,  2.72354241e-02,
           -1.58177980e-03, -5.65455444e-02, -2.13499945e-02,
            2.36055311e-02,  4.57456382e-03,  5.87781705e-02,
           -4.50953143e-03, -3.05559561e-02,  8.65572542e-02,
           -2.87776738e-02,  7.56273838e-03, -2.02421043e-02,
            4.32164557e-02,  1.07650533e-02,  1.74834915e-02,
           -2.26386450e-02, -4.51299828e-03, -7.19766971e-03,
           -5.64673692e-02, -3.46505865e-02, -9.57003422e-03,
           -4.17267382e-02,  2.74983943e-02,  7.50013590e-02,
           -1.39447292e-02, -2.10063234e-02]],

         [[-4.99953330e-03, -1.95915010e-02,  7.38414973e-02,
            3.00457701e-02,  4.11909744e-02, -4.93509434e-02,
           -3.72827090e-02, -4.84874584e-02, -1.73344277e-02,
            2.13540550e-02,  2.63152272e-02,  5.11181913e-02,
            5.94335012e-02, -8.46157200e-04, -3.79960015e-02,
           -2.01609023e-02,  2.21411046e-02, -1.14003820e-02,
           -1.78077854e-02, -6.17240835e-03, -9.96494666e-03,
           -2.70768851e-02,  3.32489684e-02, -1.18451891e-02,
            7.48611614e-02,  3.68427448e-02, -1.70680200e-04,
            2.78645731e-03,  3.37152109e-02, -6.00774325e-02,
            3.43431458e-02,  6.80516511e-02]]],


        [[[ 4.51148823e-02,  4.12209071e-02, -1.92945134e-02,
           -2.68811788e-02,  4.68725041e-02, -2.08357088e-02,
           -3.62888947e-02, -1.60191804e-02,  3.19913588e-02,
            1.54639455e-02, -7.92380888e-03, -4.85247411e-02,
           -3.52074914e-02, -1.04825860e-02, -6.63231388e-02,
            4.35819328e-02,  1.74060687e-02, -3.14022303e-02,
           -2.88435258e-02, -2.56987382e-03, -4.61222306e-02,
            9.01424140e-03, -3.54990773e-02,  3.61517034e-02,
           -4.51472104e-02, -1.96188372e-02,  2.76502203e-02,
           -3.39846462e-02, -5.75804268e-04, -4.55158725e-02,
            2.47761561e-03,  5.08131757e-02]],

         [[ 3.74217257e-02,  4.53428067e-02, -4.36269939e-02,
           -1.65079869e-02, -2.69084796e-02, -2.38134293e-03,
            2.26788968e-02, -3.10470518e-02, -4.33242172e-02,
            1.89485904e-02, -5.52747138e-02,  6.01334386e-02,
           -1.70235410e-02, -4.17503342e-02, -1.59652822e-03,
           -3.10646854e-02, -1.94913559e-02,  5.42740058e-03,
            5.47912866e-02,  2.19548331e-03, -2.94116754e-02,
            2.24571414e-02, -1.57341175e-02, -5.24678500e-03,
            4.41270098e-02,  1.79115515e-02, -3.40841003e-02,
           -2.95497216e-02,  4.40835916e-02,  4.28234115e-02,
           -4.25039157e-02,  5.90493456e-02]],

         [[-2.71476209e-02,  6.84098527e-02, -2.91980486e-02,
           -2.52507403e-02, -6.22444265e-02,  3.67519422e-03,
            5.06899729e-02,  3.09969904e-03,  4.50362265e-02,
            8.56801707e-05,  4.21552844e-02, -3.78406122e-02,
           -1.73772611e-02,  4.68185954e-02, -6.93227863e-03,
           -4.71074954e-02,  5.72011899e-03, -1.59831103e-02,
           -1.66428182e-02,  1.12894354e-02,  5.62585844e-03,
            1.36870472e-02, -2.89466791e-02, -2.87153292e-03,
           -3.21626514e-02, -3.75866666e-02, -1.62240565e-02,
            3.01954672e-02, -2.69964593e-03, -2.27513053e-02,
            2.10835561e-02, -4.13369946e-02]]]], dtype=float32),
 array([-1.1922461e-03, -2.0752363e-04,  1.1357996e-05,  1.6377015e-05,
        -2.5950783e-04,  1.9307183e-05, -1.5572178e-06, -1.3648998e-03,
        -8.6763187e-04,  4.4856939e-04,  2.7988455e-03, -7.7398616e-04,
        -5.1178242e-04, -6.8265648e-04,  1.8571866e-04, -7.1992702e-04,
        -5.5880222e-04, -3.6114815e-04, -9.7678707e-04,  2.6443407e-03,
         1.1190268e-03, -1.0251488e-03, -1.1638318e-03,  7.1209669e-04,
         4.9417594e-04,  2.3746442e-04, -4.8552561e-04,  1.4480414e-03,
        -1.8445569e-05,  4.2989667e-04,  1.0579359e-04, -3.2821635e-04],
       dtype=float32)]
```

The summary of model few starting layers

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 96, 96, 1)    0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 96, 96, 32)   320         input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (BatchNor (None, 96, 96, 32)   128         conv2d_1[0][0]
```

Now how do I order them and visualize

I am using keras

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, if you are using a Dense layer then the first lenth 2 corresponds to the weight vector and bias vector.

As I don't know the type of your layer I'm adding an example explaining shapes for Dense, Conv2D layers.

The first length always corresponds to weight and biases, the second shapes for weight and biases are different, for biases it's always an array, for Dense the weight has a shape (input_dim, output_dim), for a Conv2D (channels, kernel_h, kernel_w, num_filters).

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
import numpy as np

i1 = Input(shape=(32,32,3))
c1 = Conv2D(32, 3)(i1)
f1 = Flatten()(c1)
d1 = Dense(5)(f1)

m = Model(i1, d1)

m.summary()

y = m(np.zeros((1, 32, 32, 3)))

print(m.layers)
cw1 = np.array(m.layers[1].get_weights())
print(cw1.shape) # 2 weight, 1 weight, 1 bias
print(cw1[0].shape) # 3 channels, 3 by 3 kernels, 32 filters
print(cw1[1].shape) # 32 biases

cw1 = np.array(m.layers[2].get_weights())
print(cw1.shape) # this is just a flatten operations, so no weights

cw1 = np.array(m.layers[3].get_weights())
print(cw1.shape) # 2 -> 1 weight, 1 bias
print(cw1[0].shape) # 28800 inputs, 5 outputs, 28800 by 5 weight matrix
print(cw1[1].shape) # 5 biases
```

```
Model: "model_13"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_14 (InputLayer)        [(None, 32, 32, 3)]       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)           (None, 30, 30, 32)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_13 (Flatten)         (None, 28800)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_13 (Dense)             (None, 5)                 144005    
=================================================================
Total params: 144,901
Trainable params: 144,901
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
[<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer object at 0x7fb8ce3bb828>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7fb8ce5fd6d8>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Flatten object at 0x7fb8ce3bb940>, <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7fb8ce3bbb70>]
(2,)
(3, 3, 3, 32)
(32,)
(0,)
(2,)
(28800, 5)
(5,)
```

The visualization completely depends on the dimension.

If it's 1-D,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(weight)
plt.show()
```

If it's 2-D,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(weight)
plt.show()
```

If it's 3-D,

you can choose a channel and plot that part only.

```
# plotting the 32 conv filter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cw1 = np.array(m.layers[1].get_weights())
for i in range(32):
  plt.imshow(cw1[0][:,:,:,i])
  plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply...please check more details now..i edited my post

Comment: you can try the last answer, just plot all the conv filters.

Comment: HeyThanks it's working. So I see the filter as 3×3 for 32 filters and plotted. Now the question is that if I set my conv to conv2D(32,(28,28)), kernel size is 28×28 now will the filter be something like 28×28 image.

Comment: Exactly, the image will have dimension (kernel_h, kernel_w, channel_of_previos_input). You can discard channel if you want.